# Upgrading Swagger breaks Spring Cloud (Eureka, Zuul, Ribbon)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-cloud-netflix

I have two Spring Boot applications, one that acts as a reverse proxy for the other.  I am using Spring Boot (1.4.1.RELEASE), Spring Cloud (Camden.SR1).  I was using Swagger 2.5.0 and everything works as expected.  My BootA application, which hosts a Eureka Server and contains the Zuul mappings, successfully forwards requests it receives to the BootB application.

However, if I upgrade Swagger to 2.6.0, things start to fail.  First of all, when I look at the Eureka Dashboard, BootB application is displayed as "Unknown".  Indeed, in my application.properties for BootB, I did not define eureka.instance.appname.  If I define that in BootB's application.properties, the application is displayed in the Eureka Dashboard correctly.  Yet, the Load Balancer used by Zuul fails to find the server BootB.  I get a ZuulException (Forwarding Error) which is caused by a Client Exception from the netflix client

> 2016-11-03 14:09:09.805 [http-nio-9080-exec-10] WARN 
>   [SendErrorFilter] Error during filtering
>   com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:84)
>     at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)   at
>   com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
>     at
>   com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
>     at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
>     at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)    at
>   com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)     at
>   com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   minestar.core.app.boot.config.MinestarOAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MinestarOAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have
>   available server for client: BootB    at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468)
>     at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
>     at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)
>     at
>   rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
>     at
>   rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
>     at
>   rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
>     at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)   at
>   rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
>     at
>   rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)   at
>   rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)    at
>   rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445)
>     at
>   rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342)
>     at
>   com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102)
>     at
>   com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:42)
>     at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301)
>     at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)     at
>   rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)  at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>     at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)   at
>   rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)    at
>   rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51)
>     at
>   rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412)
>     at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:377)
>     at
>   com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133)
>     ... 112 common frames omitted

I've run with the netflix components in debug, and I can see no mention of the BootB server when using Swagger 2.6.0, yet I can see that it's found with the older release.

While I'd like to get some of the bug fixes in Swagger, this would prevent me from using it.  Assigning the eureka.instance.appname sounds like I'm treating the symptom.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting these components to work together?  On the surface, I can't see why Swagger would impact Zuul, but I'm struggling to find any root cause.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: this is a [known issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1532). It should be fixed in 2.6.1 (will be released in a day or two)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.  I'll wait for 2.6.1 and try with that version.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @DilipKrishnan  I see that the 2.6.1 Milestone has been created, but I have yet to see the 2.6.1 release of Swagger2 in Maven.  Is there a different repository that I should be using?   Or, if not, do you have an estimate on when the release will be publicly available?  Thanks.

Comment: Its out in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22springfox-swagger2%22)

Comment: Thanks... the maven search tool I was using must not have updated... got it